# Show categories on left and not on top navigation

Tags: magento, nav

I tried implemented a code in my Navigation/left.phtml

The code is as follows

```
    <!-- subcategory code -->

    <?php

    $category = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory();
    if(!$category->getChildren()){
     //$parentcat_id = $category->getParentCategory()->getId();
     //$category = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/category')->load($parentcat_id);
     $category = $category->getParentCategory();
    }
    $categories = $category->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'thumbnail'))
            ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
            ->addIdFilter($category->getChildren());
     ?>
     <div class="block">

     <div class="block-title">
        <span><?php echo $category->getName() ?></span>

        </div>
        <div class="block-content clearfix">
    <ul class="subcategories">
        <?php foreach ($categories as $category): ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $category->getUrl() ?>"><!--<img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . 'catalog' . DS . 'category' . DS . $category->getThumbnail() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($category->getName()) ?>" />-->
                    <span><?php echo $category->getName() ?>
                   <?php $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addCategoryFilter($category);

    echo "(".count($collection).")"; ?></span>
                    </a>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul></div>
    </div>
    <!-- subcategory code -->

    <!-- List all categories and their second level subcategories -->
    <div class="block block-list block-categories">
        <div id="block-categories" class="block-title active">
            <strong><span>Categories </span></strong>
        </div>

    <div id="leftnav" class="block-content" style="display:block">
        <?php $helper = $this->helper('catalog/category') ?>
        <?php $categories = $this->getStoreCategories() ?>
        <?php if (count($categories) > 0): ?>
            <ul id="leftnav-tree" class="level0">
                <?php foreach($categories as $category): ?>
                    <li class="level0<?php if ($this->isCategoryActive($category)): ?> active<?php endif; ?>">

                        <?php //if ($this->isCategoryActive($category)): ?>
                            <?php $subcategories = $category->getChildren() ?>
                            <?php if (count($subcategories) > 0): ?>
                                <ul id="leftnav-tree-<?php echo $category->getId() ?>" class="level1">
                                    <?php foreach($subcategories as $subcategory): ?>
                                        <li class="level1<?php if ($this->isCategoryActive($subcategory)): ?> active<?php endif; ?>">
                                            <a href="<?php echo $helper->getCategoryUrl($subcategory) ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml(trim($subcategory->getName(), '- ')) ?></a>
                                             <?php $secondLevelSubcategories = $subcategory->getChildren() ?>
                                             <?php if (count($secondLevelSubcategories ) > 0): ?>
                                <ul id="leftnav-tree-<?php echo $subcategory->getId() ?>" class="level2">
                                    <?php foreach($secondLevelSubcategories as $secondLevelSubcategory ): ?>
                                        <li class="level2<?php if ($this->isCategoryActive($secondLevelSubcategory )): ?> active<?php endif; ?>">
                                            <a href="<?php echo $helper->getCategoryUrl($secondLevelSubcategory ) ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml(trim($secondLevelSubcategory ->getName(), '- ')) ?></a>
                                        </li>
                                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </ul>
                                <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('leftnav-tree-<?php echo $category->getId() ?>', 'recursive')</script>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </ul>
                                <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('leftnav-tree-<?php echo $category->getId() ?>', 'recursive')</script>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php //endif; ?>
                    </li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
            <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('leftnav-tree', 'recursive')</script>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    </div>
```

But when i set Include in Navigation Menu to No it also disappears from here.
Is there any way I can hide from top menu and show in my side menu?
Demo link is http://infigic.com/ds4u/

Answer (score 0):

Changing your collection request to this should work :

```php
$categories = $category->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'thumbnail'))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('include_in_menu', 1) // there is the 'magic'
    ->addIdFilter($category->getChildren());
```

Although, I do not recommend you to do it like this.
Because:

1. You are breaking the MVC pattern of Magento when requesting a model from a view
2. You are doing over complicated things that you may probably achieve easier by doing a block which extends `Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation`, where the category may already be filtered the right way, but not rendered as you would like.

Please have a look at base Magento template (well not only the one in */app/design/frontend/base*, but the one coming with a fresh install of Magento) and you'll see that never ever are there going to be a direct call in a view to a model instance.

For Magento good practice, please refer to the perfect blog of Alan Storm (who also is a SO member) [here](http://alanstorm.com/category/magento) and maybe more specifically to [this chart](http://alanstorm.com/2009/img/magento-book/magento-mvc.png) showing how templates (view) should interact with blocks to render models.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have local.xml file just create one in the layout folder of your theme and populate it with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="header">
            <action method="unsetChild"><name>top.menu</name></action>
        </reference>

        <reference name="left">
            <action method="insert"><child>top.menu</child></action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```